# Efficiently render single-byte-per-pixel data in OpenFL?

Tags: haxe, openfl

I have a byte array that uses one byte to represent a pixel. To render it, currently I use a `BitmapData` and a loop to fill it:

```
bitmapData.lock();
for(y in 0...height) for(x in 0...width) {
    var v = data[y * width + x];
    bitmapData.setPixel(x, y, v << 16 | v << 8 | v); // grayscale
}
bitmapData.unlock();
```

But it is very CPU intensive. I wonder if there is a more efficient way, such as doing it in a shader?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the "TextRendering" sample from the Lime project to see an example of rendering from only an alpha texture. As of writing, this is not inherently support in OpenFL's renderer, but a pull request to this effect would be welcome.

The alternative would be using an `OpenGLView` with code similar to the "TextRendering" sample.